# @cython.cdivision(True) causes "math domain error" in weird scenario

Tags: math, jupyter, cython

Running a Jupyter notebook in VSCode, I am getting bizarre behavior with the Cython unprotected division directive.  Starting the session with `%load_ext cython`, run:

```
%%cython
import math
cimport cython

@cython.cdivision(True)
def simpleTest(int d):
    cdef double c = 1/math.exp(math.log(math.sqrt(2/d)))
    return c
```

Now run `simpleTest(x)` and for any value of `x` >= 3 I get:

> ValueError: math domain error

But running without the `@cython.cdivision(True)` directive it works fine for all `x` > 0, as it should.  Why does the directive break this calculation?  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling Cython to divide like in C. In C, integer division produces integer results, rounding toward 0.

With C division, `2/d` is `0` for `d > 2`. You are trying to take the logarithm of 0.